# has_many/belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 2.3.11

I have three classes: `User`, `Poster`, and `Event`

User `has_many` `Poster`, `has_many` `Event`
Event `belongs_to` `User`, `has_many` `Poster`
Poster `belongs_to` `User`, `belongs_to` `Event`

**`Event.find_by_id(@poster.event_id)`** works fine

but **`@poster.event`** does not. It used to, before I added ownership between User and Event.

If it matters:

`Poster` `belongs_to :event, :primary_key => 'static_id'`

and

`Event` `has_many :posters`, `:primary_key => 'static_id'`

The `:primary_key` bit is necessary for another part of the code (I'm not sure what it does; I don't work on that section).

I'm looking for help resolving the issue in bold, but I wouldn't complain if I ended up understanding what the :primary_key part was too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark but try

```
Event.find(@poster.event_id)
```

Is there a reason you need to specify the primary keys?  Also make sure you have the foreign keys in your `belongs_to` tables and run those migrations, i.e. Poster needs an `event_id` field, Event needs `user_id` etc.

Comment: That doesn't work (`Couldn't find Event without an ID`), but `Event.find(@poster.event_id)` does.

I really don't recall why the primary key needs to be specified.  My friend's working on a mobile app which pulls data from the server, and ... yeah, I'm really not sure. ><

Comment: Ugh, I was mistaken.  He needed primary keys specified for different models, not Poster and Event.  Fixed it by removing the primary key specification. ><

Comment: @Benjin, thanks for pointing that out - yes, it should be `Event.find(@poster.event_id)`.  Don't get in the habit of using the dynamic finders for everything especially when .find() can be used and it also raises exceptions.  You cannot do `@poster.event` as that does not return the event id; `Event.find(@poster.event.id)` should also be valid.

Comment: Why are dynamic finders something to be avoided?
What's the protocol for answers when it was my own mistake which led to the inability to find the attached event?  I just needed to get rid of the (apparently) unnecessary primary_key definitions.